# Numeric table sorting

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

Im ordering a table by room number, most rooms follow numeric value's in order such as 1,2,3,4 etc, however some room are 12A, 12B etc and the ordering takes the numbers into consideration before the letters[image]

I'm using an ngx-datatable and filtering using -

```
<ngx-datatable    
  [sorts]="[{prop: 'locationUnit', dir: 'asc'}]"
```

I would like it to filter by numbers with the letters, then the higher numbers and letters. In the example above it should be 1A, 4, 5, 12A, 12C. Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have a solution for initialize time but when you click on each header the default sort will be executed! :)

Comment: @jcalz I think OP's question is about how to apply custom sort in `ngx-datatable` I know the sort method is answered before but `How to apply in ngx-datatable`??

Comment: in ngx-table you can define a comparator in the columns: `{ key: 'room', title: "Room",comparator: this.roomComparator.bind(this) }`, the function roomComparator can be like: `roomComparator(propA, propB){ const a='0000'+propA.slice(-4); const b='0000'+propB.slice(-4); return a>b?1:a<b?-1:0}`

Comment: see a stackblitz example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-datatable-angular-bo2ntf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbasic%2Fbasic.component.ts